# Only print query

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot using Discords API. I need to print a *certain* part in the text. For example, if the input command is `!play songname`, it should print `songname`; if the input is `!play "query"`, it should print `"query"`.

I have the following code so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


TOKEN = # redacted

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Qaki.us-MB-J&L")


@client.command(pass_content=True)
async def play (ctx):
```

How can I make it print the appropriate part of the command?

Edit:

```
 
import discord
import time
import spotipy
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

Word = 'word'

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="ID", client_secret="ID"))

TOKEN = ("ID")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
 
Songname = 'word'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Qaki.us-MB-J&L")
  print(Songname)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
  Songname = (arg)
  
  if Word == arg:
    await ctx.send('Fail')
    return
  
    await ctx.send('Now playing {}'.format (arg))
  
  
  results = sp.search(q= arg, limit=20)
  for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
    print(idx, track['name'])

      

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Got it to work after finding out what args are

Comment: Is this *actually* a question about the Discord API? If you simply had a string in your program with the text `!play songname`, would you be able to write code to get the relevant part out of it? When you have the text `!play songname`,  *what is the rule that tells you* that `songname` is the part you want?

Comment: Yes this is a question about discord API, Your question is asking me what I'm asking.
I have no idea how to get the relevant part out of it.

Comment: I edited your question so that it: doesn't show your API key; avoids irrelevant chatter; and *asks an actual question*. Please read [ask]. You might also want to generate a new API key, and remember for the future that those are **private information** that you should redact whenever you post code on the Internet.

Comment: Anyway, it's not possible to help you like this, because we can't understand where you're stuck. But based on what I'm hearing, I would suggest that you practice writing things that work at the command line for a few months before worrying about things like connecting a bot to Discord. Learn to walk before you run.

Comment: This is a website where questions are asked. It is not a *forum* where people teach the basics of programming. There are standards that apply to the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use `*, arg`. This is shown in the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments). Using this will give you the full 'query' given by the person who initiated the command.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg) # sending in channel that the command was initiated in
    print(arg) # printing to console
```

[image: Showing the test command works]

To view other parts of this, such as specific arguments, single-word arguments, etcetera, please start from [the top of the linked page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer.
I found the Discord.py documentation shortly after asking the question originally
I was using the API but wasn't looking in the EXT section my bad

Comment: If you feel that this was the answer to this question, don't forget to close it by pressing the tick beneath the upvote/ downvote buttons.